# How can I attach an object to a fixed location on an image?

Tags: html, css, image, position

Until now I only figured out how to put an object to a fixed location with the page coordinates. 
Here is the Problem:

When I move the image (the objects are points on the image where you can click on) up/down/left/right the points are staying at the old location.

So is there a way to give them coordinates from the image? Then I could move the img around and the points would stay where they are, wouldn't they?

These are my Points (CSS):

```
div.point {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #7ab51d;
    border: 3px solid white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

These how I position them:

```
<div id="Restroom_Water" class="point" style="top:380px;left:1000px;" onmouseover="$('#Restroom_text_Water').show();" onmouseout="$('#Restroom_text_Water').hide();"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the position attribute:

```
div.point{
    position: relative;
}
```

This means the pixel position of the point object are relative to the parent container (in this case your image).

[This article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) goes over positioning pretty well.

Comment: So I need to put the points the the same container as the img right?

Comment: Correct. That container is fixed, but the points are relative. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfuh2pf0/